# How to position the symbols the right way?

Tags: uncharted-3

I'm stuck at yet another puzzle in the French chateau in *Uncharted 3*.

This time I have to position several symbols over each other to unlock a door:

[image]

The notebook has the following tips, which only tell me what to do with the eagle and the horse, but not the other two symbols:

[image]

I tried putting them over the same symbols as the other two, but that doesn't seem right. Mirroring the pattern upside down either, so I really have no idea which should go where.

**So what's the solution for this puzzle?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this walkthrough](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/960/1/Uncharted-3-Walkthrough-Chapter-6---The-Chateau/Page1.html):

> Get each symbol to its position according to the Journal:
>
> Eagle should be on Bottom row, middle square. 
>   Horse should be on Second from bottom row, leftmost square.
>
> For the other two symbols, locate the reflective floor symbols around the room. Look how the light from your torch is reflecting on the floor there. The symbol changes depending on where you're standing. Use that to figure out where the other symbols should go. The solution is:
>
> Bull should be on middle row, fourth square (from the left)
>   Lion should be on fourth row from bottom, second square from left.

[image]

Comment: I took a photo of Drake's journal that shows the solution to the puzzle. http://i.stack.imgur.com/93m95.jpg