# How to cross the room with symbols on the floor

Tags: uncharted-3

What is the logic behind the room with the symbols on the floor in the French Chateau? I realise I need to follow the directions in the journal, but it seems that even when I take exactly the same path I fail at different points.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34066/how-to-position-the-symbols-the-right-way

Comment: Not a duplicate, they are different puzzles (in the same French Chateau area).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is given in Ashley's answer, but here's the logic: your notes give you how many of each tile design you need to step on, from bottom to top. There's only one path that lets you step on exactly that many of each tile in sequence, which is given in Ashley Nunn's answer.

Comment: I prefer this answer to Ashley's as the OP was specifically asking for the logic behind the puzzle, not its solution.

Comment: I realised after I asked the question that I had been doing the symbols in top-down order rather than bottom-up. It's embarrassing how long it took me to notice.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this walkthrough](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/960/1/Uncharted-3-Walkthrough-Chapter-6---The-Chateau/Page1.html), you need to do the following:

> Start on the start symbol (yellow circle with half moon below it.) and then move according to the following sequence:
>  FORWARD, LEFT, FORWARD,RIGHT,FORWARD,FORWARD,LEFT,DOWN,LEFT,FORWARD,RIGHT,RIGHT,RIGHT, FORWARD,LEFT,FORWARD

For reference, here is [the picture in the journal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJawb.gif).

Comment: Ashley, you may want to consider putting the puzzle solution behind spoiler tags (not sure if that's possible with images though), so readers don't inadvertently read it

Comment: @Alex Post sanitized on Ashley's behalf.